# Can Nagios be used on embedded devices

Tags: nagios

Is anyone using Nagios monitoring tool on embedded devices. I m looking for cross compiling the tool for ARM platform. Is there any other open source monitoring tools that can be used?

Thanks,
Chitra

Comment: This question is not designed for SO.  Please refer to: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  You didn't even make the effort to complete the 2-minute site tour.